# Azure App Service IIS - Going down

Tags: windows, iis, azure, cloud

I hope you can help me here since Im more a DEV than a Server / Infra person.

I have a site hosted in AZURE, with the following tier.

[image]

It is a fairly simple site [TuGrieta](http://www.tugrieta.com) where you allow people to chat in different rooms.

The problem im facing is that the IIS or the WP gets unresponsive and the app goes down.

I have been checking the Azure Portal Metrics and apparently what is happening is that the commited memory reach **~60% around 2GB** the process restarts. Code is disposing objects, is not a leak.. confirmed.

[image]

The app goes down and we receive a **5XX error**. Is there a setting in Azure to disallow that restart / refresh / recycle?

For example, see this chart. This happend yesterday, we received a peak of people (requests) and IIS couldn't handle it and restarted and 5xx started.

[image]

I'm a developer so Im sorry if Im not providing enough information, just let me know if I can provide more info.

Comment: I believe IIS is crashing because of memory leak or lack of resources in general, although the usual behaviour is to just slow down dramatically your site, not crash. You could try running a higher tier for a little while just to confirm this and in the meantime, you can use tools such as Application Insights or Newrelic to get to the bottom of the problem.

Comment: What are the exact 5XX errors? Microsoft does have a guide on how to identify IIS status code and then troubleshoot on each, https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/943891